# Getting values using index in List C#

Tags: c#, list

I am Searching for Desired output, Here is the right place where I can get that.

I have two List in c# as ids1list ,ids2list

```
ids1list:
Title
nen154
source

ids2list:
tittl
Title
nen154
WTOC
source 
style
```

I am comparing these two as `var result = ids1list.Intersect(ids2list).ToList();`

In result I am getting Common Values
Here I want Index of ids2list Which are Common values in ids1list

Some on Suggested me like this,

```
        ids1list.Select(s => new 
        {
            Id = s, Index = ids2list.IndexOf(s) 
        });
```

But It not yet worked for me,
Can anyone give me proper solution.
Because I strucked here.

Comment: what is the type of list? `List<string>`?

Comment: So you want those that have the same index?

Comment: Yes, It is List<String>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to select the second list if you want it's indices:

```
IEnumerable<int> indices = ids2list
    .Select((s, i) => new{ Str = s, Index = i })
    .Where(x => ids1list.Contains(x.Str))
    .Select(x => x.Index);
```

Another approach similar to yours:

```
indices = ids1list
    .Select(s => new{ Str = s, Index = ids2list.IndexOf(s) })
    .Where(x => x.Index >= 0)
    .Select(x=> x.Index);
```

Comment: I have a feeling that is not what he's looking for.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: _" I want Index of ids2list Which are Common values in ids1list"_

Comment: I don't know how you can understand that :P

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Speaking "New User" is an acquired skill.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It seems Very nice, I want to go through it, & I have a Doudbt on this. What is `IEnumerable<int>`
Can I use it as a `list`.
Why because using theseindex I going to fetch Values from third `List`,Thanks.

Comment: @kumar: you can use ToList() to create a List<int>.